# Manually set UI Language?

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there any way to manually or programmaticaly set the UI Language so that in my tests I can get a different results from GetUserDefaultUILanguage? Or anyone know the settings within Windows where I can change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To truly test the customer it's best not to mess around with the setting and actually get a copy of windows in a different language. This is the approach I finally decide on.

Answer (score 0):

If your testing on vista/win7 install other language packs (windows update -> optional extras) and hot swap over to other languages.

Comment: No luck, I have an entreprise version of Vista and 2008

Comment: The Enterprise version of Vista is supposed to have that capability.  Server 2008 does have that capability and I've used it.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Vista this is a standard feature (for XP there was special Multilingual MU) version.

Choose "Regional and language Options" from the Control panel and then go to the "keyboards and languages" Tab. In the lower part of it you can add additional UI languages and select one of the installed ones. After choosing a different UI Language you must log off and log on again to see the results (No reboot needed though). Then you see the whole Windows GUI n the whatever selected language.

Comment: That is a standard feature for Vista Ultimate and Enterprise, not for other versions of Vista.